# USB camera on raspberry pi integrated with google assistantstreaming video

Tags: raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

I was trying to make a home assistant out of raspberry pi. So I integrated my pi to google assistant. Now i have a USB camera which can stream video using motion. I want my google assistant to open my browser and go to the url of motion "http://ip_of_the_pi:8080". Can you please help me with the steps I need to follow?

Comment: Is the Google Assistant embedded into your Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Yes! It is embedded to my raspberry pi.

Comment: In that case I think the best way to do this is to create [custom device actions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/device-actions-overview#custom) that will open the browser when you give a particular phrase.